# Excel - Return the value of a particular cell based on matches of other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet that looks similar to the following:

```
  A         B                 C        D           E           (DESIRED RESULT, F)
TIME1  IP_ADDRESS1          TIME1  IP_ADDRESS1   DOMAIN1              DOMAIN1
TIME2  IP_ADDRESS2          TIME2  IP_ADDRESS2   DOMAIN2              DOMAIN2
TIME3  IP_ADDRESS3          TIME3  IP_ADDRESS3   DOMAIN3          DOMAIN3 / DOMAIN4
TIME3  IP_ADDRESS1          TIME3  IP_ADDRESS3   DOMAIN4                  -
TIME3  IP_ADDRESS2          TIME4  IP_ADDRESS4   DOMAIN5                  -
TIME4  IP_ADDRESS4          TIME5  IP_ADDRESS5   DOMAIN6              DOMAIN5
TIME5  IP_ADDRESS5          TIME5  IP_ADDRESS6   DOMAIN7                  -
```

What I have been wracking my brain trying to do is equivalent to the following:
If the Time in column A matches a Time in column C, then check to see if the IP address in column B is also in column D, then return the matching domain in column F.

For example, in the above worksheet DOMAIN1 is returned first because the time and the domain matches in both sets of columns. DOMAIN3 / DOMAIN4 is returned because there are two domains with the same Time AND IP Address. Hopefully that makes sense.

I've tried variations of INDEX, MATCH, VLOOKUPS, etc. but I just can't seem to get it.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, your last row should have DOMAIN6 in the result and you can do this with the following formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" / ",TRUE,IFERROR(FILTER($E$2:$E$8,($C$2:$C$8=$A2)*($D$2:$D$8=$B2)),"-"))
```

In other words, filter all rows for column E where the corresponding value in column C matches the current row in column A and the corresponding value in column D matches the current row in column B.

If that `FILTER` returns nothing, then simply return a dash.

For arrays returned with more than one item, join them with the specified separator.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This has done the majority of the work, I just need to do a few more manual edits, but this has helped so much! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. What kind of manual edits? Perhaps the formula can be improved.